# Using Angular ngStyle with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

[This stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zs7ez2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) is using `ngStyle` to style the `h1` element like this:

```
<h1 [ngStyle]="{'background-color':backgroundColor}"
```

The `HelloComponent` also uses `OnPush` change detection strategy:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1 [ngStyle]="{'background-color':backgroundColor}">Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
```

When the background color is updated to `yellow` in `ngAfterViewInit()` the view does not update and the color remains as blue.

How do we trigger change detection, such that the style will update?

I tried `this.cdr.markForCheck()` to see if I could trigger it.

Comment: if you are using ngAfterViewInit most likely you are doing something wrong. try puting the logic inside of ngOnInit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console of your stackblitz says `ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'blue'. Current value: 'yellow;'..`

You simply have a typo.
Change

`this.backgroundColor = 'yellow;'`

to

`this.backgroundColor = 'yellow';`

(move semicolon to outside the string value)

Comment: Awesome!!  Good catch! Thanks!!  I changed the code to use `OnInit` instead of `AfterViewInit` and now the error is gone.  Thanks again.